# How to give an email functionality for FORGOTTEN PASSWORD Field in CFML[coldfusion]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coldfusion

I have created a forgot password page and an update password page...
How to send email link of update password page to users who click forgot password button using coldfusion.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function myFunction()
     { 
        
        var newpassword=document.getElementById("newpassword").value;
        var confirmpassword =document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;
        if(newpassword==confirmpassword)
        {  
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          alert("Confirm password is not same as your new password.");
          return false;
        }
     }
      
</script>
```

```css
//This is forgot password page
<body>
  <script>
              function chkValues()
               {
           if(document.getElementById('emailid').value == '')
                 {
                  alert("Please enter emailid");
                 return false;
                 }
                 alert('hi, Password sent');
                 alert(document.getElementById('emailid').value);
                 return false;
               }
 </script> 
   </head>
 <body>
   <div class="Forgot password">
   <div class="form">
      <form class="forgot password">
      <input type="text" placeholder="emailid" name="emailid" id="emailid" value=""/>
      <br>
      <button onClick="javascript:chkValues();">Login</button>  
</form>
 
       <a href ="Login.cfml"> Go Back to login</a>


 </body>
```

```html
<form name="updatepassword" id="updatepassword" method="post" action="updatepassword.cfml">

<div class="updatepassword" style="display:;">
       <tr>
          <td>
               New Password
          </td> 
               <input type="text" placeholder="New Password" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" value="" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters">
   </tr>
   <tr>
          <td>
               Confirm Password
          </td> 
               <input type="text" placeholder="confirm Password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" value="">
   </tr>
      <br>     
            <input type="submit" name="updatepassword" value="updatepassword" onClick="javascript:return myFunction();"/>  
            
<cfoutput>
 <cfif isDefined('URL.username')>
  <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="#URL.username#">
 <cfelseif isDefined('form.username')>
  <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="#form.username#">
 </cfif>
</cfoutput>
      
</div>
</form>
```

I have created a forgot password page and an update password page...
How to send email link of update password page to users who click forgot password button using coldfusion.

Comment: Hi Madhu, your question is a little too broad to provide a good answer. Have you tried anything yet? Please include a [mcve] of your attempts

Comment: hi tshimkus.., i have added my code. If there is anything needed let me know. Thank you

Comment: you can try the link of updatepassword.cfml by passing the email id